# XDocument Save String parameter doesn't exists in net.core

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, .net-core

In my old projects when I save a XDocument, the Save function has like 7 overloads including a "string fileName"

Now in my new project using Net Core there's no overload accepting a string where the document should be saved.

I have this:

```
XDocument file = new XDocument();
XElement email = new XElement("Email");
XElement recipientsXml = new XElement("Recipients");
foreach (var r in recipients)
{
   var rec = new XElement("Recipient",
       new XAttribute("To", r));
   recipientsXml.Add(rec);
}
email.Add(recipientsXml);
file.Add(email);
file.Save(@"C:\1\email.xml");
```

How I save the XDocument in my disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found how to do that.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\1\emails.xml");
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings);

XDocument file = new XDocument();
XElement email = new XElement("Email");
XElement recipientsXml = new XElement("Recipients");
foreach (var r in recipients)
{
   var rec = new XElement("Recipient",
       new XAttribute("To", r));
   recipientsXml.Add(rec);
}
email.Add(recipientsXml);
file.Add(email);
file.Save(writer);

writer.Flush();
fileStream.Flush();
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `using(FileStream fileStream = ...) { ...}`

Answer (score 2):

You can save the `XDocument` like this, but you need to add some [`SaveOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) ([implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b119ec518b1ccc13e420862ff68dfbbd3bfee28e/src/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs#L706)). Have a look at the [Implementation of XDocument](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b119ec518b1ccc13e420862ff68dfbbd3bfee28e/src/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XDocument.cs#L764):

```
public void Save(string fileName, SaveOptions options)
{
    XmlWriterSettings ws = GetXmlWriterSettings(options);
    if (_declaration != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_declaration.Encoding))
    {
        try
        {
            ws.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(_declaration.Encoding);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
        }
    }

    using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, ws))
    {
        Save(w);
    }
}
```

You can implement your own solution using a writer, or simply call the existing method like

```
file.Save(@"C:\1\email.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

Comment: I can't do that: file.Save(@"C:\1\email.xml", SaveOptions.None); What version of NetCore is that?

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 contains the shown System.Linq version 4.2.0.0

Comment: I'm using 1.1 :(

Comment: In this case you could add the implementation to your code